# How to output text from database with line breaks in a django template?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-templates

I have text saved in a database record that looks like this.

```
This is the text

This is on a new line with a space in between
```

When I output it on the Django template, it comes out like this

```
This is the text This is on a new line with a space in between
```

How can I output the text on my django template to reflect the way it appears in the database?

Comment: use `<br>` after `{{text|linebreaks}}`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use [`linebreaks`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks) or [`linebreaksbr`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaksbr) filter:

```
{{ text|linebreaks }}
```

Or surround the text with `<pre>...</pre>`.

```
<pre>{{ text }}</pre>
```

Answer (score 3):

I `linebreaks` uses `<p>` tag to convert new line, this will probally not preserve the empty line or you will just not see it due to css styling.
You can try instead [linkebrksbr](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaksbr) that will use `<br/>` for new lines.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `<br/>`

`<br/>` is an HTML code. Don't forget you are working with HTML using Django. Keeping this in mind will solve a lot of beginners trouble.

Answer (score 0):

`<pre>` tag works fine, but has some default declarations (like monospace and margins).

The solution for me was to take the essence of the `<pre>` tag - the following declaration:

```
white-space: pre;
```

And modify it (if you don't need extra spaces):

```
white-space: pre-line;
```

Now the data from the database fields `models.TextField` keep all the line breaks.