# space between paragraph missing after looping in a <div>?

Tags: python, django

Im trying to make it so that if my textfield has a {startformat}, it will make the following text look like code and with the  change the background. But once it goes in and out of the , any space between paragraph goes missing, making everything one big text.

```
    <h2 class="article-title">{{ object.title }}</h2>
    <p class="article-content">
    {% for line in object.content.splitlines %}
    {% if line == '{startformat}'%}<div class="card-header"><code class="text-dark">
    {% elif line == '{stopformat}'%}</code></div>
    {% else %}{{line}}
    {% endif %}{% endfor %}
    </p>
```

Output!!!

Quo inani quando ea, mel an vide adversarium suscipiantur. Et dicunt eleifend splendide pro. Nibh animal dolorem vim ex, nec te agam referrentur. Usu admodum ocurreret ne.

```
Quo inani quando ea, mel an vide adversarium suscipiantur. Et dicunt eleifend splendide pro. Nibh animal dolorem vim ex, nec te agam referrentur. Usu admodum ocurreret ne. Quo inani quando ea, mel an vide adversarium suscipiantur. Et dicunt eleifend splendide pro. Nibh animal dolorem vim ex, nec te agam referrentur. Usu admodum ocurreret ne.
```

Quo inani quando ea, mel an vide adversarium suscipiantur. Et dicunt eleifend splendide pro. Nibh animal dolorem vim ex, nec te agam referrentur. Usu admodum ocurreret ne. Quo inani quando ea, mel an vide adversarium suscipiantur. Et dicunt eleifend splendide pro. Nibh animal dolorem vim ex, nec te agam referrentur. Usu admodum ocurreret ne. Quo inani quando ea, mel an vide adversarium suscipiantur. Et dicunt eleifend splendide pro. Nibh animal dolorem vim ex, nec te agam referrentur. Usu admodum ocurreret ne. Quo inani quando ea, mel an vide adversarium suscipiantur. Et dicunt eleifend splendide pro. Nibh animal dolorem vim ex, nec te agam referrentur. Usu admodum ocurreret ne. Quo inani quando ea, mel an vide adversarium suscipiantur. Et dicunt eleifend splendide pro. Nibh animal dolorem

There should be a couple of paragraphs in the bottom text

Comment: in and out of the div*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538454/how-to-output-text-with-line-breaks-in-a-django-template Needed to specify 'linebreak' when i output the variable.